# Undefined reference to VK::Client

Tags: c++, vkontakte-api, makefile

```
using namespace std;
#include <iostream>
#include <vk_mast/src/api.h>

int main(){

VK::Client api;
if(api.auth("login", "pass", "token")
cout<<"ok";
else
cout<<"peredelyvai";
return 0;
}
```

Выдаёт ошибку undefined reference to 'VK::Client::Client(...)' и 'VK::Client::auth(...)'
Написал в точности как на примере в ридми файле.
cURL установлен, IDE - codeblocks 17.12, minGW (стоит флаг -std=c++11).
Библиотека - https://github.com/Kolsha/VK

UPD: Не подключил библиотеку, но я не знаю как открыть makefile. Msys пишет command not found (путь к mingw и msys в path указал).

Comment: МОжет надо библиотеки подключить?

Comment: @xverizex там makefile есть, но его не могу никак "запустить". msys пишет command not found, make-ом не знаю как пользоваться, через cmd тоже не получается.

Comment: `mingw32-make`  — make

Comment: @ヒミコпробовал разные варианты, пишет "no rule to make target" или "no such file or directory". Везде пишут, что нужно писать просто mingw32-make, но чтобы файл находился в директории, вот только в какой директории я понять не могу.

Comment: Так это же для линукса makefile, у вас ничего не выйдет. Все подключаемые места из линукса взяты и компилятор тоже. Вам надо g++ менять на свой, который в windows. Если же у вас линукс, то установите компилятор g++. Судя по makefile он ищет из каталога /usr/local/lib, в local/lib обычно помещаются библиотеки, которые сам устанавливаешь из исходных кодов. Если бы библиотека установлена была из пакетов, то бралось бы из /usr/lib. Это для линукса.

Comment: ЕЩё вроде его можно открыть в qt-creator и скомпилировать оттуда. Попробуйте.